# Avoid Parent model class creation in Django

Tags: django

I have the following data models:

```
class PaymentGateway(models.Model):
    GATEWAYS = Choices(
        ('stripe', _('Stripe')),
        ('paybox', _('PayBox')),
        ('generic', _('Generic')),
    )

    tenant = models.ForeignKey(Tenant, 
related_name="payment_gateways")
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        verbose_name=_('Name'),
        choices=GATEWAYS,
        default=GATEWAYS.generic
    )

class StripeGateway(PaymentGateway):
    stripe_public_key = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    stripe_key = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'Stripe Gateway'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StripeGateway, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.name = PaymentGateway.GATEWAYS.stripe

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Stripe data for %(school_name)s" % {"school_name": self.school.name}


class EtransactionGateway(PaymentGateway):
    pbx_site = models.IntegerField()
    pbx_rang = models.IntegerField()
    pbx_identifiant = models.IntegerField()
    pbx_devise = models.IntegerField()
    pbx_secret = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'Etransaction Gateway'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EtransactionGateway, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.name = PaymentGateway.GATEWAYS.paybox

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "E-transaction data for %(school_name)s" % {"school_name": self.school.name}
```

This is fine, but when I create an instance of either StripeGateway or EtransactionGateway, I can see another instace of PaymentGateway is created.

I've tried creating the PaymentGateway abstract as suggested [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name-aEDIT: I've tried, based on comments, to add abstract to parent class and then I runnd-related-query-name) but when I do this and run the migration (I already run a first migration with the current scenario) then I get an error saying something like id field in eTransactionGateway conflicts with the one from paymentGateway (sorry I can't find the trace now).

For now this is ok, but I'd really like to not have instances of PaymentGateway or at least, have the backref payment_gateways return the children classes, because right now something like this:

```
tenant = Tenant.objects.get(name='tenant_1')
gws = tenant.payment_gateways.all()
```

Return the parent instances, that have no value for me.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT: I've tried, based on comments, to add abstract to parent class and then I run**

So classes look like these now:

```
class PaymentGateway(models.Model):
    GATEWAYS = Choices(
        ('stripe', _('Stripe')),
        ('paybox', _('PayBox')),
        ('generic', _('Generic')),
    )

    tenant = models.ForeignKey(Tenant, related_name = "%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related")

    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        verbose_name=_('Name'),
        choices=GATEWAYS,
        default=GATEWAYS.generic
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class StripeGateway(PaymentGateway):
    stripe_public_key = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    stripe_key = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'Stripe Gateway'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StripeGateway, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.name = PaymentGateway.GATEWAYS.stripe

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Stripe data for %(school_name)s" % {"school_name": self.school.name}


class EtransactionGateway(PaymentGateway):
    pbx_site = models.IntegerField()
    pbx_rang = models.IntegerField()
    pbx_identifiant = models.IntegerField()
    pbx_devise = models.IntegerField()
    pbx_secret = models.CharField(max_length=255)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'Etransaction Gateway'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EtransactionGateway, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.name = PaymentGateway.GATEWAYS.paybox

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "E-transaction data for %(school_name)s" % {"school_name": self.school.name}
```

I've reset db first

```
python manage.py reset_db
```

And then

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

And getting this messages like this:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'id' to etransactiongateway without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option: 


You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'tenant' to stripegateway without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
```

1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
   2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py

I select 1, since I don't even have the id field in my children classes (this is managed internally by Django), for second message I use id of a tenant I already know exists in db with id 1

Get this output afterwards:

```
Migrations for 'payment':
0010_auto_20170704_2305.py:
  - RemovEDIT: I've tried, based on comments, to add abstract to parent class and then I rune field tenat from paymentgateway
  - Remove field paymentgateway_ptr from etransactiongateway
  - Remove field paymentgateway_ptr from stripegateway
  - Add field id to etransactiongateway
  - Add field name to etransactiongateway
  - Add field tenant to etransactiongateway
  - Add field id to stripegateway
  - Add field name to stripegateway
  - Add field tenant to stripegateway
  - Delete model PaymentGateway
```

This migration looks weird to me, but anyway, let's try migrate, this is the output:

```
  Applying payment.0010_auto_20170704_2305...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 25, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/acme/python_envs/acme/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/home/acme/python_envs/acme/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/acme/python_envs/acme/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/acme/python_envs/acme/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/acme/python_envs/acme/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/acme/python_envs/acme/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 92, in migrate
self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/acme/python_envs/acme/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/acme/python_envs/acme/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 198, in apply_migration
state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/acme/python_envs/acme/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 115, in apply
operation.state_forwards(self.app_label, project_state)
  File "/home/acme/python_envs/acme/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 51, in state_forwards
state.reload_model(app_label, self.model_name_lower)
  File "/home/acme/python_envs/acme/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 148, in reload_model
self.apps.render_multiple(states_to_be_rendered)
 File "/home/acme/python_envs/acme/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 296, in render_multiple
model.render(self)
  File "/home/acme/python_envs/acme/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 585, in render
body,EDIT: I've tried, based on comments, to add abstract to parent class and then I run
  File "/home/acme/python_envs/acme/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 223, in __new__
'base class %r' % (field.name, name, base.__name__)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field u'id' in class 'EtransactionGateway' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'PaymentGateway'
```

Comment: Please provide the exact error message, and make sure that all your migrations are created and applied.

Comment: If you are still in development you could backup yor migrations, delete them and `makemigrations` again.

Comment: You probably also need to drop the existing database.

Comment: I did all that, python manage.py resetdb and python manage.py migrate, and still getting errors, let me try again so you can see the error

Comment: Check my last edit please

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a table for the parent model in the db, you could add `abstract=True` in the model's metaclass.

```
class PaymentGateway(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Source: [Django abstract base classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes)

Comment: Please read my question thoroughly, already did that, and it is not working, as you can see in my edit.

Comment: have you tried deleting all of your migration files?

Comment: No, but I won't do that, I have more than 300 migration files and I won't delete them all because of this small change, this is part of a huge project

Comment: I meant the migrations concerning this change to your models.

Comment: Will give it a try